# Process first n-files in the directory

Tags: ruby

I have a function which prosecces first N files in the direcory:

```
def restore(cnt)
  $LOG.debug "store_engine : restore tweets from cache (cnt = #{cnt})"

  result = TweetCollection.new

  Dir["cache/*"].each do |path|
    cnt = cnt - 1
    File.open(path) do |f|
      result.append(Tweet.construct(:friends, :yaml, f.read))
    end
    if cnt == 0
      return result
    end      
  end

  result
end
```

I'm just wondering if there is a more ruby-way method to write this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002160) the array with `[]` and use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003129) to collect all `Tweet` objects in  the `TweetCollection`. Use [`File.read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002245) to return the contents of the file at the given `path` in one method call.

```
def restore(count)
  @log.debug "store_engine: restore tweets from cache (cnt = #{count})"
  Dir["cache/*"][0...count].inject(TweetCollection.new) do |tweets, path|
    tweets.append Tweet.construct(:friends, :yaml, File.read(path))
    tweets
  end
end
```

I have also replaced your global variable by an instance variable; I don't know the context of your method, so this may not be possible.

Comment: +1. Something about inject that my brain tries to block it out.. nicely applied here.

Answer (score 1):

[Slice it](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002160):

```
Dir["cache/*"][0...cnt] do |path|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Dir["cache/*"].take(cnt)
```